# AWS EC2 web server: can't connect by domain name

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, amazon-web-services

I've set up a very simple EC2 Apache web server. To help debugging I've stripped it back to a hello world page: 52.50.28.188. It all works OK by this address.

I've also registered a domain name: [michaelpidgeon.co.uk](http://www.michaelpidgeon.co.uk). This immediately hits an error.

However - by navigating directly to the index file itself, it works no problem on this domain name: [michaelpidgeon.co.uk/index.html](http://www.michaelpidgeon.co.uk/index.html)

I've tried fiddling around with the AWS Route 53 settings and as far as I can tell everything is set up OK, with a public hosted zone. I've also made sure DirectoryIndex points to index.html in my httpd.conf.

I'm at a bit of a loss where to go next, apart from scrapping this EC2 and just starting again.

Any help really appreciated.

Comment: When I navigate to http://michaelpidgeon.co.uk I see "hello world". What exactly is your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The links posted above point to `www.micahelpidgeon.co.uk`, for which there is no DNS record:

```
$ dig www.michaelpidgeon.co.uk

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> www.michaelpidgeon.co.uk
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 11395
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.michaelpidgeon.co.uk.  IN  A

;; Query time: 28 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.3.1#53(192.168.3.1)
;; WHEN: Thu Mar 10 14:32:28 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 42
```

You'll need to create a record for `www` and then configure your webserver to serve requests to that domain.

Comment: Thank you, I've realised this was a caching issue in the browser. Apologies for stupid question. You've made me think about creating a DNS record for the www though so I will do some more research into that.

Comment: Create a CNAME that points to the main A record